# println works with get not with set, why?

Tags: swift

I want to know about the execution process of  computed get and set properties.

My code is here:

```
var operandstack = Array<Double>()
@IBAction func enter()
    {
        println("FUNCTION enter")
        typingNew = false
        operandstack.append(displayvalue)
        println("\(operandstack)")

    }
var displayvalue : Double {
    get { 
        println("get value==\(display.text)") 
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    } 
    set { 
        println("set vaslue== \(newValue)") 
        display.text="\(newValue)"
        typingNew=false
    }
}
```

`println` works in `get` method and not in `set`, and also I need to know which gets executed first.

I am using Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.4

[image]

Comment: You don't call the `set`, do you?

Comment: i have updated the code i just called the displayvalue in my code.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to Xcode 7 / Swift 2.

Comment: @Thomas How do I explicitly call the setter?

Comment: @AravindhKumar see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the get part is being called if you are accessing the value of displayvalue, while the set part will be called once you change the value in displayvalue.

```
var x = displayvalue // get will be called --> print(get value== ..)
displayvalue = 2.0   // set will be called --> print(set vaslue== 2.0)
```

Comment: You are right. Using the statement `displayvalue = 2.0` calls the set function. But when I use `operandStack.append(displayvalue)` the set function is not called. I don't know why.

Comment: You are appending the operandStack, the value of displayvalue will not be changed by that call. Only operandStack will be changed.

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot. I understand now that only assignment statement will call setter.

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
var operandstack = Array<Double>()
@IBAction func enter()
    {
        println("FUNCTION enter")
        typingNew = false
        operandstack.append(displayvalue)
        println("\(operandstack)")

    }
var displayvalue : Double {
    get { 
        println("get value==\(display.text)") 
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    } 
    set { 
        println("set vaslue== \(newValue)") 
        display.text="\(newValue)"
        typingNew=false
    }
}
```

you **never** use the `setter`. Try to assign a value to `DisplayText` and you'll see the print.

For example:

```
var operandstack = Array<Double>()
@IBAction func enter()
    {
        println("FUNCTION enter")
        typingNew = false
        displayvalue = 2.0 // <-- Here you use the setter
        operandstack.append(displayvalue)
        println("\(operandstack)")

    }
```

---

By the way, the code `operandstack.append(displayvalue)` calls the `getter` since you want to *get* the value of `displayvalue` and put it in `operandstack`

Comment: You answer is right too. Sorry I saw it later. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

To call the get method, you have to assign a new value to your computed property `displayvalue`. That's the only chance when the get method will be called.

As to your second question, it depends on if you get the property first or assign new value to it first.